# Wrong display of items with PHP code

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following issue:

I am showing multiple items from a database in my website. They look fine, ordered 2x2.

```
A  B
C  D
E  F
```

However, in the 4th row, only 1 of the items is shown and then the next item is in the following row.

You can check the tests at http://www.tahara.es/store

My code looks like this:

```
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{

?> 
<div name='item' id='<?php echo $info['color_base1']; ?>' class='itemBox'>
    <div class='showItem'><a href='items_descr.php?itemId=<?php echo $info['id_item']; ?>'>
        <img class='itemImage' alt='' src='<?php echo "../images/".$info['imageMid']; ?>.jpg'>
        </img>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class='indexItemText'>
        <span class='similarItemsText'>
            <a href='items_descr.php?itemId=<?php echo $info['id_item']; ?>'><?php echo $info['name']; ?></a>
             - $<?php echo $info['price']; ?> </span>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $row_count++;

if ($row_count % 2 == 0) 
    {
echo "<br />"; // close the row if we're on an even record
    }

}               
?>
```

Comment: For one thing, you have a PHP error on the page, maybe it's related



Notice: Undefined index:  color in /var/www/vhosts/tahara.es/httpdocs/store/indexMain.php on line 3

Comment: You also have a stray php closing tag on line 23 of source, closing </img>(?) tags, and `Acceso autorizado.` echoed at the top of the page.  Try making the markup valid.

Comment: Thanks, but those 2 details do not affect the display of the items... any other suggestions?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `<br />` in your html to do formatting. You should use CSS for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CSS issue. you can resolve it by adding `clear:both` to the `<span>` elements that cause line breaks in your code.

Currently, you are listing the photos in pairs. You force a line break between each pair with an empty `<span>` tag, like this:

```
A    B
-- span --
C    D
....
```

However, this `<span>` tag doesn't play nice with all of the `<div>`s because the `<div>`s are floating. Elements that float render in different locations than elements that do not float. In this specific case, all of your `<span>` tags actually render near the top of the page:

```
-- span --
-- span --
A    B
C    D
...
```

You can force the `<span>`s to respect the location of the floating elements by adding the `clear` CSS attribute to them:

```
span {
display: block;
clear:both; /* this element will respect the location of anything that floats right or left */
}
```

I would also consider adding a class to this specific `<span>`. `<span>` is a common element and causing all of them to `clear:both` might have unintended consequences.